# Expand targeted Splunk search to include all hosts, build report

Tags: splunk, linux-disk-free

I am trying to run a search against all hosts but I am having difficulty figuring out the right approach. A simplified version of what I am looking for is:

```
index=os sourcetype=df host=system323 mount=/var | streamstats range(storage_used) as storage_growth window=2
```

But ultimately I want it to search all mount points on all hosts and then send that to a chart or a report.

I tried a few different approaches but none of them gave me the expected results. I felt like I was on the right path with sub-searches, because it felt like the equivalent of a for loop but it did not yield the expected results

```
index=os sourcetype=df [search index=os sourcetype=df [search index=os sourcetype=df earliest=-1d@d latest=now() | stats values(host) AS host] earliest=-1d@d latest=now() | stats values(mount) AS mount] | streamstats range(storage_used) as storage_growth window=2
```

How can I take my first search an build a report that will include all hosts and mount points?

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler than sub-searches.  Just use a by clause in your streamstats:

```
index=os sourcetype=df 
| eval mountpoint=host+":"+mount 
| streamstats range(storage_used) as storage_growth by mountpoint window=2 
| table _time,mountpoint,storage_growth
```